# Angularjs + Bootstrap + Modal box width resize based on content

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angularjs and boostrap.

I need to show the preview for images and pdf files in that popup.
I have input for only file name with path.
But i unable to show the preview based on the image width. for example image have 500px means the popup should be show the 500px width. 
IF the image have more than 900px means the popup size is fixed width 900px.

Which is the best to load the images and pdf file?

Iframe or ...?

I attached my code here. I induced the image file is hot-coded, the file name is auto generated.

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/rajinikumarr/8MVLJ/1523/)
html code:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/master/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">

    <h3>Angular Modal Service</h3>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>
    <p>
        {{message}}
    </p>

    <!-- The actual modal template, just a bit o bootstrap -->
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
        <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Image</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>It's your call...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <img src="http://slideshare-wordpress-blog-pictures.s3.amazonaws.com/ethos3-Theme-cover.jpg">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </script>

</div>
```

Js code:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, ModalService) {

    $scope.show = function() {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl : 'modal.html',
            controller : "ModalController"
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                $scope.message = "You said " + result;
            });
        });
    };

});

app.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close) {

    $scope.close = function(result) {
        close(result, 500);
        // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
    };

});
```